# How to split a CSV file into multiple files based on a text string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have multiple text files (CSV) with a structure similar to this:

```
funkiana,23.55,-99.866
funkiana,24.634,-98.701
funkiana,24.717,-98.901
geminiflora,22.25,-104.6166667
geminiflora,21.21666667,-104.65
horrida,19.633,-97.367
horrida,23.61666667,-102.575
horrida,22.158,-100.979
horrida,19.506,-97.433
horrida,17,-97.56667
horrida,19.485,-97.263
horrida,19.017,-99.133
horrida,19.017,-99.15
horrida,18.91,-99.23
horrida,17.82167,-100.26333
horrida,19.507,-97.438
inaequidens,19.399,-99.314
inaequidens,23.58333,-105.8833
inaequidens,19.767,-103.7
inaequidens,20.787,-103.848
```

As you can see, there are three fields (species, latitude and longitude). Now, I want to split each CSV file into different CSV files, containing only the data of each species. In other words, I want a file for all the occurrences of `funkiana` (with lat/lon), another for `geminiflora` (with lat/lon) and so on.

Any ideas on how to do this? Maybe with a script or an Excel macro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The fastest method I could think of is to use PowerShell

```vb
$fullpath = "D:\myFolder\input.csv"

$path = Split-Path $fullpath -parent
$data = Import-CSV -Delimiter "," -Path $fullpath -Header species,latitude,longitude  

foreach ($group in $data | Group species){        
    $data | Where-Object {$_.species -eq $group.name} | 
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
        foreach {$_.Replace('"','')} | 
        Out-File "$path\$($group.name).csv"     
}
```

1. Paste the code to a new text file and save it as e.g `MySplitMacro.ps1`
2. Edit the first line and change `$fullpath` to your desired CSV path
3. Right-Click the `.ps1` file and click *Run with PowerShell*

Taking your initial example as input, the script will create 4 new CSV files at the same location as your input file. Each CSV will contain one set of entries when filtered by first column.

<sub>**Resulting example folder**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**One resulting example file**</sub>
[image]

#### Tweaks

- Change *species* in `$data | Group species` to set the column to filter for
- Change `-Delimiter ","` if your input file has a different delimiter like tabs "`t" or semicolons ";"
- Change `-Header species,latitude,longitude` to your column names. Order it properly
- Change `$path\$($group.name).csv` if you need a different output path
- Instead of `-eq $group.name` to filter your results you could also use `-like *$group.name*` for wildcard comparison or `-match '[A-Z]$group.name'` for [RegEx comparison](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html)

#### Used resources

- http://ss64.com/ps/import-csv.html
- http://ss64.com/ps/group-object.html
- http://ss64.com/ps/convertto-csv.html
- http://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html
- http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html

Comment: Beautiful answer...sorry I can only upvote it only one time.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted to do :) . I will check the resources you used. Definitely, I need to learn Power Shell scripting. Thank you again.

Comment: @nixda Thank you for the answer. I used the powershell script and it nicely spits out the CSV files as intended. But the encoding on this is *UCS-2 LE BOM*. The Excel cannot parse the CSV file properly since it is different encoding. How to change it to *UTF-8*?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is commonly referred to as "control break" process.
There is a "control" value. In your case, it's the species. When this changes values or "breaks" we want to do something. In your case, you want to write out a new file.

There are numerous ways to solve your problem.  I would typically use a scripting language vs. Excel to solve it.

This link has a walk through if you're interested in learning how to write such a program/script: 
http://www.unix.com/tips-and-tutorials/209439-how-do-control-break-algorithm.html

If you're on a Windows platform and don't mind using a programming language, you can use LinqPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) which has a free edition and the following C# program (be sure to select "C# program" in the LinqPad Language dropdown):

```
void Main()
{
    var path = @"c:\sourceGit\speciesLatLon.txt";
    var inputLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    // Holds all the lines to be added to each output file
    var linesForCurrentSpeciesFile = new List<string>(); 

    // Read first row
    int i = 0;
    var currentSpecies = GetSpecies(inputLines[i]);

    // initialize hold value
    var holdValue = currentSpecies;

    // Initialize output values
    linesForCurrentSpeciesFile.Add(inputLines[i]);

    // Read next value
    i++;

    while( i < inputLines.Length )
    {
        currentSpecies = GetSpecies(inputLines[i]);
        if (currentSpecies !=  holdValue)
        {
            // output current file
            WriteSpeciesFile(holdValue, linesForCurrentSpeciesFile);

            // Initialize new output file by clearing out the previous
            linesForCurrentSpeciesFile.Clear();

            // update hold value with the value just examined.
            holdValue = currentSpecies;
        }
        // Add the current line to the output file
        linesForCurrentSpeciesFile.Add(inputLines[i]);
        i++;
    }
    // Write the output file because last row is equal to a break in the sequence
    WriteSpeciesFile(currentSpecies, linesForCurrentSpeciesFile);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public string GetSpecies(string line)
{
    // return the first value of the input line
    return line.Split(new char[] {','})[0];
}

public void WriteSpeciesFile(string species, List<string> content)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(@"C:\sourceGit\{0}.csv", species), content.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have very little experience with programming (that's one thing that I want to solve asap), but definitely I'll check your suggestion. Also, thanks for mentioning the name of the process. I had doubts about the title of the question because I didn't know how to define it :P.

Answer (score 0):

A simple csv search app like CsvFileSearch will do this without the need to get complicated.It will search multiple files and save the results into another file.

Comment: But can it also *split* a file into multiple files?

Comment: Add more detail into your answer